# How to add click actions to go through list of links inside a variable ? Power automate desktop

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have simple flow:

```
1- Launch new Chrome with url `https://www.google.com/search?q=2022+games`
2- Extract data from web page into variable `%DataFromWebPage%`
```

Here is the flow

[image]

Here is the data:

[image]

How I can visit or click each link in the `%DataFromWebPage%` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if you just want to know how to access the items in the variable `%DataFromWebPage%`  or need to navigate to the urls in the list and then extract data from each page.

It looks like you extracted the information into a data table/list so you can access the values using the index or the name. [see the microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/variable-data-types#datatable)

In your example you can use a loop or for each loop and navigate to each page.

Copy either of the 'code' sections below and paste it in your flow.

```
LOOP FOREACH currentRow IN DataFromWebPage
    WebAutomation.GoToWebPage.GoToWebPage BrowserInstance: Browser Url: currentRow[1] WaitForPageToLoadTimeout: 60
END
```

or use a loop

```
LOOP LoopIndex FROM 0 TO DataFromWebPage.Count - 1 STEP 1
    WebAutomation.GoToWebPage.GoToWebPage BrowserInstance: Browser Url: DataFromWebPage[LoopIndex][1] WaitForPageToLoadTimeout: 60
END
```

Comment: yes I need to go to each url and extract another data. What syntax is that you are using ? I am using flow like in the picture below

Comment: The syntax is what you get if you copy the flow and paste it to notepad. I forgot to mention you can select the text above and paste it to your flow, it will then show as in the picture below.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me with for each loop and `%currentitem[1]%`

[image: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/286086]